# changing API_URL isn't taking effect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am very new to Angular and JS space. I cloned a repo to play around with it. I followed all the instructions and everything worked fine. But when I make a change to `API_URL` in this code https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth/blob/master/app/scripts/services/djangoAuth.js then nothing happens. Its almost like the code isn't taking effect. I reload the page, restart nginx, but absolutely nothing. The console of chrome shows that its still trying to make request to old API_URL value. I've also re-ran `npm install` and `bower install` but same problem.

Is there some basic thing I'm missing? I think this should take effect immediately after I restart nginx and reload the page. Am I missing something with `bower`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may miss changing the initialization [phase](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth/blob/47d1283cddd60c0b1a49e27a35102fd93719b7ef/app/scripts/app.js), at the bottom of this file

```
run(function(djangoAuth){
  djangoAuth.initialize('//127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth', false);
});
```

Remember to change the url here.